# The verb beware in a subjunctive clause

Tags: subjunctive-mood, contemporary-english, inflections

I know that nowadays in English the verb "beware" can be used only in imperative clauses and in bare infinitival constructions to warn or to guide. I've understood that nowadays "beware" can't be inflected.

Would it be okay to use "beware" in a subjunctive clause like in "It's essential that she beware of the dog." or does it sound weird or ungrammatical?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's a bare infinitival construction to warn or guide. Why do you think it's ungrammatical with _beware_?

Comment: I've submitted an edit removing the "old-english" tag as whilst this question does deal with a feature that may be old-fashioned in contemporary speech, it's still entirely about the language Modern English, and not Old English, which had already developed into Middle English 800 years ago

Comment: I had always read *beware* as a shortening of *be aware (of)* or *be wary (of)*, as an imperative; the longer versions inflect in the usual way.  I would read "It's essential that she beware of the dog" as an unusual usage but with an understandable intended meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds fine to me, but as it turns out, the usage is rather rare. In fact, I could only find a handful of relatively recent examples where it's clearly the subjunctive (by which I assume was meant the use of a plain form of a verb in a declarative content clause allowed by verbs such as *suggest*, as in *I suggest you **be** on time*).

> However, I am a suspicious sort and so I suggest to the workers and
> their trade union representatives that they **beware** of Tories
> bearing gifts (2003, Ms Maria Eagle, British House of Commons)
>
> I am aware that Chimamanda Ngozi Adichie well knows this saying by her
> own illustrious uncle and our icon, Chinua Achebe:' Until the lions
> have their own historians, the history of the hunt will always glorify
> the hunter.' In the light of this quote, I would urge that we
> **beware**, even in this season of anomie, the dangers of a single story. ([Guardian](https://guardian.ng/opinion/2023-presidential-elections-and-adichies-so-wrong-a-letter/))
>
> Just as she was enjoying the thought of becoming Mrs. B, an anonymous warning arrived , suggesting that she **beware** of a sham marriage. (Masterplots: Revised Category Edition, British Fiction Series; Frank Northen Magill · 1985)
>
> I would suggest to the Senator that he **beware** he does not fall into the same error which our former Chairman of the Joint Economic Committee , the former Senator from Illinois - Mr . Douglas - used to fall into (United States. Congress. House. Committee on Ways and Means · 1967)

Answer (score 3):

If I ignored the sign "beware of the bull" on the gate into a field and climbed over the gate, ignoring the warning, and were then tossed by the bull, I wouldn't bother complaining to the farmer.  If I did, I would probably get the answer: "Well, I warned you to beware, and you *did not beware*.".

The Cambridge online Dictionary gives examples of its use, all of which match the idea that 'beware' is never used as an ordinary verb.  The examples are of imperative or modal usage.

> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beware

The fact that *beware* is not used in all the ways of other standard verbs does not entail that there is a *rule* against such usage.  People don't tend to use it as an ordinary verb for an understandable reason.

*Beware* is made up of the verb *be*, and *ware*.  There is a useful account of this in *Etymonline*:  [https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=beware&ref=searchbar_searchhint]

So it was originally (in the 12th century CE) indeed not an ordinary verb to be used in different tenses.  "Be" is the base form of the copula, and the base form of verbs is also the imperative form.  That did not stop two famous English writers, Dryden and the good Dr. Johnson (the author of the first English dictionary).  It is fair to say that some uses seem weirder than others, and that in any case, its main use is on notices rather than in conversation.  The word *beware* for the purposes of everyday language looks moribund. That is a prediction that it will come to look increasingly old-fashioned and so become non-standard.  But that does not render it incorrect or forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

As @Tuffy says, *beware* etymologically originates from the base form *be*, so it's understandable that it can only take the base form.

The subjective form in a mandative construction can certainly have *be* as the subjunctive form, so I don't see any reason why the base form *beware* cannot be used in the construction.

Granted, this usage is few and far between, but at least [one 2020 New York Times article (book review)](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/04/03/books/review/john-kay-mervyn-king-radical-uncertainty-stanislas-dehaene-how-we-learn-anthony-david-into-the-abyss.html) agrees with me:

> The 2008 financial crisis is, of course, an excellent example of the ways that the past may be a disastrous guide to either the present or the future. Most of the data leading into the crisis wasn’t much help in predicting it, and the lived experience of most so-called experts didn’t help either. Kay and King skewer pre-crisis pomposity and they tell diverse and fascinating stories about corporate culture, the inequitable remuneration of chief executives, the hunt for Osama bin Laden, the manufacturers of the Airbus, NASA and the traffic app Waze. Their book is demanding, and at times difficult, but it is also an elegant and careful guide to thinking about personal and social economics, especially in a time of uncertainty. The timing is impeccable. The authors advise that you **beware** experts who use words like confidence, likelihood and probability interchangeably, and never underestimate the value of asking the deceptively simple question: What is going on here?

Answer (score -1):

No. Beware is a [defective verb](https://www.thoughtco.com/defective-verb-english-grammar-4085836), as follows:

> Beyond the modal auxiliaries, beware is a fully-fledged defective verb
> of English: it is used as an imperative (beware of the dog) and an
> infinitive (I must beware of the dog). ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb#:%7E:text=Beyond%20the%20modal%20auxiliaries%2C%20beware,(*bewared%2C%20*bewares).))

Being able to also be used with [modal auxiliaries](https://www.english.cam.ac.uk/elor/lo/modal-auxiliary-verbs/index.html) allows for one to say things like:

- You must beware.
- He should beware.
- I would beware if I were you.

While the last example uses the subjunctive mood, it uses it in the "if" clause. The verb "beware" isn't in the subjunctive mood.

Comment: -1: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beware) disagrees with Wikipedia; it says *beware* may be used as a subjunctive. Since the form of the subjunctive is the bare infinitive, this is consistent with *beware* not being inflected.

Comment: @PeterShor Wikipedia and Wiktionary are pretty weak authorities, only slightly better than ChatGPT.

Comment: @Mitch: I agree. Maybe somebody can find a better authority. (Maybe not; it's a rare usage, so I think it may be something of a judgment call to say whether it's grammatical or not.)

Comment: English does not have a mood system, other than that marked mostly by the modal auxiliaries. The subjunctive is thus not a mood form but a clause type headed by a plain form verb. "I were you" is not a subjunctive construction at all; in modern grammar this "were" is sensibly best called 'irrealis' mood.

Comment: @BillJ - "English does not have a **mood** system"? I beg to differ, and so do you, for you yourself say, "in modern grammar this 'were' is sensibly best called 'irrealis' **mood**." As a point of fact, all subjunctive conjugations are not tenses but are **moods**.

Comment: @PeterShor - If you notice, I used not one but two authorities in my answer. In addition to Wikipedia, I also use ThoughtCo., which in its definition and explanation of "defective verb" (first link in my answer), states: "Beware is a defective verb being used only in the imperative or to give a caution. . . " With two grammar authorities in agreement, any disagreement, even by another authority, becomes opinion.

Comment: I said "marked **mostly** by the modal auxiliaries". Irrealis "were" is the only other item, an isolated mood form. The term 'subjunctive' is generally applied to an inflectional category of the verb, but modern grammar reinterprets it as a syntactic construction - a clause that is finite but tenseless, containing the plain form of the verb. English once had an inflectional mood system applying to all verbs, but this was lost in earlier stages of the language. The meaning distinctions are now conveyed by tense with the modals (and irrealis "were") being the only remnants of the earlier system.

Comment: "The subjunctive isn't a tense. It's a **mood**." -Grammarly (https://www.grammarly.com/blog/subjunctive/)

Comment: "The subjunctive **mood** is the verb form used to explore a hypothetical situation." -Grammar Monster (https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm)

Comment: "The subjunctive **mood** expresses wishes, suggestions, demands, or desires..." -Merriam-Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/getting-in-the-subjunctive-mood)

Comment: "The subjunctive is not a verb tense; it's called a '**mood**'." -Appalachian State University (https://www.appstate.edu/~fountainca/1050/unidad3/subjformas.html#:~:text=The%20subjunctive%20is%20not%20a,fewer%20than%20the%20indicative%20mood.)

Comment: I didn't say the subjunctive is a tense. I said it is **tenseless** Read my comment properly. I hardly think that Grammarly and Grammar Monster are scholarly authorities on grammar, and no serious grammarian uses dictionaries for grammar.

Comment: I didn't say you did say it was a tense. I said that you said "English does not have a **mood** system," which you did say that, that's wrong, and these citations where I've shown "**mood**" in bold prove that. Your attempt to shift the argument to that I said you said the subjunctive is a tense, an assertion I never made and an assertion that you've made up because it's easily defeated, is your failed attempt at a strawman.

Comment: The citations you quote are nothing more than schoolboy grammar. I've already explained why they are not worth bothering with. The fact is that there is no verb in modern-day English that is inflected for mood other than 'irrealis' "were", an untidy relic of an earlier system and often replaced with preterite "was".

Answer (score -1):

Examples of the mandative subjunctive found with Google Books:

> But it was not just Bertani who wrote; for all who knew Garibaldi seemed to believe in his need for advice and his accessibility to
> theirs. A number of them now sent it, redundantly **demanding that he
> "beware of [Giuseppe] La Farina.**" [Raymond Grew; *A Sterner Plan for
> Italian Unity*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Sterner_Plan_for_Italian_Unity/1BLWCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=insist%20he%20beware&pg=PA343&printsec=frontcover) (2015)

> His reason still clamored a warning, **crying that he beware of this
> child of the Eldreds**, that the only foundation for his hope that her
> hands were clean and her record free from duplicity was a wild guess.
> [Harold Titus; *The Beloved Pawn* in *Everybody's Magazine, Vol
> 48*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Everybody_s_Magazine/Up7PAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22that%20he%20beware%22&pg=PA36&printsec=frontcover) (1923)

> Belshazzar listened in surprise to her desperate **prayers** that he
> surround himself with every protection, **that he beware against
> venturing out at night**, that he wear armor under his tunic, and that
> he carry weapons of defence always around with him. [Margaret Horton
> Potter; *Istar of Babylon*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Istar_of_Babylon_A_Phantasy/iO3CDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22that%20he%20beware%22&pg=PT325&printsec=frontcover) (1902)